# How to create form with multiple fields. Objects Ant design React Js

Tags: reactjs, forms, dictionary, object, antd

I am making a form in Antd where I must send 2 string fields (name and description) and objects that are buttons that contain an object inside that are checkboxes.

It turns out that the latter I don't know how to implement it, if with a <Form.List /> or some other solution. Here is an example of how I should send the information:

```
"name": "Consultor",
"description": "",
"edit_permissions_grid": {
       "1": {
           "name": "Main menu",
           "description": "Menu features",
           "url": "/menu",
           "selected_permissions": {
               "add": true,
               "delete": false,
               "edit": false,
               "query": true,
               "download": false,
               "play": false
           }
       }
```

I am already sending the name and description correctly. The problem is the 'edit_permissions_grid' how to nest it or how to work it together with the 'selected_permissions'. Here is my current form:

Name y description:

```
          <Form.Item
            name="name"
            style={{ minHeight: 50, marginBottom: 10 }}
            rules={ getRolFormRules('name', allRoles) }
            initialValue={data?.name}>
            <TextArea
              onChange={ validatorLength }
              placeholder="Ej: Supervisor"
              autoSize={{ minRows: 2, maxRows: 2 }}
              maxLength={ 30 } />
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            name="description"
            style={{ minHeight: 50, marginBottom: 0 }}
            rules={ getRolFormRules('description') }
            initialValue={data?.description}>
            <TextArea
              className="form-textarea"
              autoSize={{ minRows: 2, maxRows: 2 }}
              maxLength={ textAreaMaxLength } />
          </Form.Item>
```

'edit_permissions_grid':

```
      <Form.Item
        name="edit_permissions_grid"
        style={{ minHeight: 50, marginBottom: 0 }}>
          {/* Buttons = Views */}
          {
            !_.isEmpty(data?.permissions_grid) &&
            Object.entries(data?.permissions_grid)
              .map(([key, value]) => (
                <Button
                  align="left"
                  className="view-buttons"
                  onClick={() => { props.buttonSelection(value.permissions_template)} }>
                  {value.name} 
                </Button>
            ))
          }
          {/* Checkboxs = Permissions */}
          {
            !_.isEmpty(dataPermissions) &&
            Object.entries(dataPermissions)
              .map(([key, value]) => (
                value &&
                  <Row className="check-permissions">
                    <Checkbox
                      onChange={onChange}>
                      {key}
                    </Checkbox>
                  </Row>
            ))
          }
      </Form.Item>
```

The traversal of the objects that I do are with data from the backend. NOTE: Clicking on each button shows you the associated permissions (set of checkboxes)

The idea is that each button (views) saves me the information of each checkbox (permissions) selected. Attached below visually as seen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U70K2.jpg)

How can I do to send 'edit_permissions_grid' correctly, should I create a <Form.List /> or how?

Thank you very much to all for reading.